# TreeSet / Contains method

Tags: java, collections, treeset

As an exercise, I try to implement my own `TreeSet`. Before coding the add and remove methods, I prefer start by contains which seems more easy but I'm stuck.

My Tree is composed with `Node` and `Leaf` :

```
static class Leaf<E extends Comparable<E>> implements Tree<E> {

                 //stuff
        @Override
        public boolean contains() {
           return false;
        }

}
```

Here's the `Node` class :

```
static class Node<E extends Comparable<E>> implements Tree<E> {

    private final E value;
    private Tree<E> left;
    private Tree<E> right;

   //some stuff
   @Override
   public boolean contains(E elem) {
       //here i'm blocked
   }
}
```

How can I say to my tree to look into the good part of it (left or right) with the element ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use recursivity !

As you can see the `Leaf` objects compose the end of the `Tree`, so it will be the stop condition of the method.

You can see that the objects that will be stocked in the `Tree` have to implements `Comparable`. So contains can look like this :

```
@Override
public boolean contains(E elem) {
    int compare = elem.compareTo(value); //here we compare the element with 
                                         //the compareTo method that the objects 
                                         //used must redefined

    if(compare==0)
            return true; //here the current node contains elem !
        else if(compare < 0)
            return left.contains(elem); //elem is inferior than the elem present in the current node hence we look into the left part of the tree
        else
            return right.contains(elem); //elem is superior than the elem present in the current node hence we look into the right part of the tree
    }
```

As you can see, if the element isn't present in the `Tree`, we will be in a `Leaf` at the end and it will return `false`.

You can implement the same logic to code `add` and `remove`

Answer (score 2):

> How can I say to my tree to look into the good part of it (left or right) with the element ?

Well, you need to compare `elem` with `value` using `compareTo`. If the result is 0, then the values are already equal, and you can return `true`.

If `elem` is less than `value`, then you can recurse into `left.contains(elem)`, otherwise recurse into `right.contains(elem)`. If the `left` or `right` value is just a leaf, that will return `false`, otherwise it will recurse down appropriately.